# JTree TreeCellRenderer not highlighting selection

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I wrote a tree renderer for a JTree of files and it can set the background color when the tree is first made, but it does not highlight selections.

```
private class CustomTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer{
    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus){
        if(value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode){
            setText(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemDisplayName((File) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject()));
            setIcon(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon((File) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject()));
        }
        super.setBackgroundSelectionColor(Color.BLUE);
        if(selected){
            super.setBackground(Color.gray);
            setForeground(getTextSelectionColor());
        }else{
            super.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            setForeground(getTextNonSelectionColor());
        }
        this.setOpaque(true);
        return this;
    }
}
```

adding

```
super.getTreeCellRendererComponent
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Inside getTreeCellRendererComponent, the first call should be

```
super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(arguments);
```